# Adapting a working prepared statement call with an older version of php

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to setup prepared statements on a server that is unable to use get_result(). Below are the functions I call. This is working code I have on a site that is on a server that can use get_result() so I  know the code works to an extent.

((EDIT HERE))
With this code my $dbarray is coming back blank. I'm simply trying to make it return the rows being pulled from the db.

Here are my two functions used.

```
protected static function BuildParam($parameters){
        //If $where is an array then we have to extract the values and their type so we can bind_param();
        if(is_array($parameters)){
            foreach($parameters as $value){
                $param = (is_array($value) ? $value[1] : $value);
                $params[] = $param;
                $paramType = '';
                switch($param){
                    case is_int($param):
                        $paramType .= 'i';
                        break;
                    case is_float($param):
                        $paramType .= 'd';
                        break;
                    case is_string($param):
                        $paramType .= 's';
                        break;
                    default:
                        $paramType .= 'b';
                }
            }

            $params = array_merge(array($paramType), array_values($params));
            if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0) //Reference is required for PHP 5.3+
            {
                $refs = array();
                foreach($params as $key => $value)
                    $refs[$key] = &$params[$key];
                return $refs;
            }
            return $params;

        }
    }

//string $q = mysql query
//array $parameters = where clause parameters
protected function QueryFetchArray($q, $parameters = ''){
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q);

    //If $parameters is an array (if there are parameters)
    if(is_array($parameters)){
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), self::BuildParam($parameters));
    }
    $stmt -> execute();

    ((EDIT HERE))
    //What I use on the new server that I cannot use on this server
    //$result = $stmt -> get_result();
    //This is where I'm stuck and trying to replace the above line
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){$result[] = $row;}

    $stmt -> close();


    if($result !== NULL){
        $dbarray = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }else{
        $dbarray = NULL;
    }
    return $dbarray;
}
```

Comment: `$results` stored a boolean value of which the statement was successfully executed or not (TRUE, in your case). Your results are in the $dbarray variable. What is your question?

Comment: $result could never be null, if it's coming from mysql_query. it'd be either boolean false, or a statement handle. mysql_query CAN'T return null. only false/statement are possible.

Comment: I made edits to my post trying to answer your question Aedix. My goal is simply to make $dbarray = to the pulled results. I also threw in where im trying to adjust the code for an older server at ((EDIT HERE))